# Назначение операторов в jquery

Tags: jquery

С помощью jquery под копирку сделал простенький эффект параллакса на сайте.

Механика понятная, но хотелось бы более глубокого понимания.

Код параллакса вот такой:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

var st = $(this).scrollTop();

$(".header_text").css ({
    "transform" : "translate(0%,-" + st + "%)"
})
});
```

Но хочется понять, **почему** он такой? Что значит $? Что значит window? this? Почему значения css задаются таким образом ("селектор" *двоеточие* "параметр")?

Я гуглил, но все описания слишком академические. Хочется объяснения для совсем тупых. :)

Comment: операторы в Вашем коде - это знак "равно" и два плюса. `$()` - это функция, возвращающая объект, содержащий выборку элементов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ - элемент, с помощью которого начинается любая конструкция в jQuery. Также можно писать jQuery(window).scroll({...}). Без этого это уже не jQuery будет...

window - элемент javascript, подробнее: [MDN документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window). Если коротко - выбирается всё окно сайта, со всем DOM

this - указывает на текущий элемент (в данном случае на window). Если бы было не window, а например, #mydiv, то в this передалось бы #mydiv. Если это указывать в html по onclick="$(this).css({...})", то в this передалось значение текущего элемента, к которому навешено это свойство, и в данном случае изменились бы его стили.

Значения задаются в виде свойств объекта, если их несколько (но можно и одно указать в таком же виде). Если одно, можно задать как .css('param', 'value')... Подробнее тут: [jQuery Wiki](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_CSS) (тут уже и совсем тупому будет понятно, что и к чему)

Главный вопрос - почему оно такое? Потому что такие стандартны были заложены при создании javascript и библиотеки jQuery.
И привыкайте разбираться в, как Вы выразились, "академических" документациях. Без этого далеко не уедете.